# How to earn bronze Tag badge?

Tags: discussion

The help for this type of badge states:

> You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge

So what does that mean exactly? How do I earn one?

Answer (score 3):

These Tag Badges are for the number of votes you accrue on your answers a particular Tag. The instructions just set out how answers you need and how many votes you need between them.

In this case, 20 questions with at least +100 votes between them.

Comment: Well you get 10 rep from every upvote, so you only need 10 upvotes for a bronze (not 100).

Comment: corresponding tag creater can only be able to earn this badge.

Comment: @Braiam Had a senior moment, thanks.